# Setting a default js url in a header

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to set a var of 'default_url' in the header of my file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var default_url = <?php echo $default_url ?>;
</script>
```

But I keep getting an error that there is an unexpected <

Is there anyway for me to actually do something like that?

Comment: When this is seen by the browser, it will read like `var default_url = http://www.example.com` and it will be invalid javascript (because the string is not quoted). Try `<?php echo json_encode( $default_url ); ?>`

Comment: Assuming `$default_url` is housing a string, you may want to also wrap that php statement in quotes. e.g. `var default_url = '<?php echo $default_url; ?>';` (Also, as i re-type this, you're missing a semicolon.)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var default_url = '<?php echo $default_url ?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var default_url = "<?php echo $default_url; ?>";
</script>
```

Specifically note that I added a semicolon and quotes.

Comment: that semi colon does not make any difference.

Comment: @itachi it's good to get into the habit of properly terminating your statements, however.

Comment: @Mansfield: I never down-voted. I very rarely do so unless the author just plain doesn't care or they're horrifically off-base (e.g. answer in a language completely different than OP's question). So given you answered in PHP (and not c++) and were more than willing to update your question, all is well. ;-)

Comment: My mistake. Whoever it was changed it anyway...and it's hardly the end of the world regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes on the outside of the  tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var default_url = "<?php echo $default_url; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: LOL oops, see two more similar answers :)